# Do not have .NET Framework 4.5 multi targeting pack in VS 2012 Ultimate

Tags: .net-4.5

I have install microsoft vs 2012 ultimate into windows 7, but it does not include .net framework 4.5 multi targeting pack. So, where can I get the multi targeting pack and install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here on MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks): .NET Framework Multi-Targeting Packs and SDK’s for Visual Studio 2012

Comment: its not there now